# How to change this statement from mySQL to PostgreSQL

Tags: mysql, postgresql

How to change this command from mySQl to PostgreSQL?

`SELECT * FROM 'student' WHERE CONCAT('first_name', 'last_name', 'phone', 'address')LIKE ?`

Comment: What does Postgres say about it? Have you done even a superficial search for "concat in postgres"?

Answer (score 1):

The code should work in postgresql too  but you should not use single quote around column name

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM student 
 WHERE CONCAT(first_name, last_name, phone, address) LIKE ?
```

could be your "like" matching param need  some wildchar

```
 SELECT * 
 FROM student 
 WHERE CONCAT(first_name, last_name, phone, address) LIKE concat('%',?,'%')
```

Comment: says to 1) ERROR: syntax error at or near ";" and to 2) ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Comment: update your question and add the exact code you are using  .. anyway answer  updated removing unclear ;